# How to know what are included with the Android Framework

Tags: android

I can't distinguish which class in [android framework](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) must be added to dependency when using.

Although [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) is included in android framework, why do I have to add this library to dependency manually?
If the reason is that RecyclerView class is in Support Library, what other classes in android framework need to be added?

Answer (score 0):

You can have Android Studio import them automatically for you as you use them. You can turn it on at Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import.

Comment: what I mean is not "import statement". It's "dependency" at Project Structure -> app -> Dependencies